Force a widget to rebuild from anywhere?
I cant really find a simple way to just rebuild a widget from outside it.
I guess this might be "by design", that you're not supposed to do it this way. But desperate times (deadlines) calls for desperate measures, so is there any way to tell a widget to rebuild (for example a Builder, or even the top most MaterialApp.builder) from anywhere in the code?
Note that I don't want to restart the application, just rebuild a specific widget somewhere in the widget tree.
Simplified example:
MaterialApp(
   
  builder: (context, child) {
    if( securityModel.appIsLocked ) then return LockScreen();
    return child;
  },

  home: MainScreen(),

  routes: {
    '/page1': (context) => Page1Screen(),
    '/page2': (context) => Page2Screen(),
  }

)


class SecurityModel(
  bool appIsLocked = false;

  void lockApp(){
    appIsLocked = true;

    /*******
     Force MaterialApp.builder() to rebuild, to replace the entire app with `LockScreen()` 
    *******/
  }
)
   


This question is similar to: How to set state from another widget?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You could achieve this by wrapping your widget in a StreamBuilder widget.
Then create a Stream on a global scope that you use as a parameter for your Streambuilder widget.
You can then simply use the myGlobalStream.add(newValue) method from anywhere to update your widget.
Let me know if you need a code sample, but it should be pretty straight-forward.

Thanks. I ended up doing something similar. Since the app is using ScopedModel I created a separate Model for this special use case, and used a ScopedModelDescendant inside the MaterialApp.builder method. It feels a bit backwards to use a ScopedModelDescendant directly in the MaterialApp.builder itself, but it does seem to work. I guess behind the scenes, ScopedModel is doing something similar to your solution when calling notifyListeners().
